# Solr 7.2.1 and Sitecore 9

Tags: solr, sitecore

I have installed solr 7.2.1 and enabled SSL and it seems it works fine. However, I'm trying to install Sitecore 9 on a local dev environment now, following the installation guide located at: https://dev.sitecore.net/Downloads/Sitecore_Experience_Platform/90/Sitecore_Experience_Platform_90_Initial_Release.aspx

But I get the error below, the error occurred after successfully creating cores, windows services, xconnect website, apppools and databases. Can't think of something I didn't try. I'm using the Solr default Manage-Schema configurations. Didn't change it.

```
[ConfigureSolrSchemas [1]]:[Requesting] https://localhost:8984/solr
[ConfigureSolrSchemas [1]]:[Schema] Modifying Schema on https://mysolr:8984/solr : iuhpp_xdb
Invoke-ManageSolrSchemaTask : No such field type 'long'
At C:\Program
Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\SitecoreInstallFramework\1.1.0\Public\Install-SitecoreConfiguration.ps1:253 char:21
+                     & $entry.Task.Command @paramSet | Out-Default
+                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Write-Error], WriteErrorException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorException,Invoke-ManageSolrSchemaTask

Invoke-ManageSolrSchemaTask : No such field type 'double'
At C:\Program
Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\SitecoreInstallFramework\1.1.0\Public\Install-SitecoreConfiguration.ps1:253 char:21
+                     & $entry.Task.Command @paramSet | Out-Default
+                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Write-Error], WriteErrorException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorException,Invoke-ManageSolrSchemaTask

Invoke-ManageSolrSchemaTask : No such field type 'date'
At C:\Program
Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\SitecoreInstallFramework\1.1.0\Public\Install-SitecoreConfiguration.ps1:253 char:21
+                     & $entry.Task.Command @paramSet | Out-Default
+                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Write-Error], WriteErrorException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorException,Invoke-ManageSolrSchemaTask
```

Comment: The installation guide in section 2.1.6 states that only SOLR 6.6.1 is supported, although there is a known issue with this version and 6.6.2 has worked for most of us. Would also suggest you install Sitecore 9.0 Update-1 since it is a more recent release (again with SOLR 6.6.2)

Comment: Now Sitecore 9.1 officially supports Solr 7.2.1, see a compatibility table [here](https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/227897)